# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ntp.ntpc'

Tags: debian, packaging, ntp, python3, module

I'm building package **ntpsec-1.1.3+dfsg1** in **buster** but failed when compiling. The error is:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ntp.ntpc'
```

I saw that there are some *.py* files in the package need **ntp.ntpc** module by grep but I can't find where to install the module.

```
build/main/pylib/packet.py:197:import ntp.ntpc
build/main/pylib/util.py:16:import ntp.ntpc
build/main/ntpclients/ntpq:27:    import ntp.ntpc
build/main/ntpclients/ntpmon:38:    import ntp.ntpc
pylib/packet.py:197:import ntp.ntpc
pylib/util.py:16:import ntp.ntpc
ntpclients/ntpq.py:27:    import ntp.ntpc
ntpclients/ntpmon.py:38:    import ntp.ntpc
```

How to fix this?

Comment: Which version is this about ? Please edit your question to include **ntpsec** version. .... Default is `apt install ntpsec` : Provides version 1.1.3+dfsg1-2 → https://packages.debian.org/buster/ntpsec

Answer (score 0):

07 Oct 2019

ntpsec, Debian Buster https://packages.debian.org/buster/ntpsec

ntpsec, Debian Sid  https://packages.debian.org/sid/ntpsec

**ntpsec**, build-example 1 : `# apt-get build-dep ntpsec`

Or / and `# apt install build-essential asciidoc bison debhelper dh-apache2 dh-apparmor dh-python docbook-xsl libcap2-dev libssl-dev netbase pps-tools python3 python3-dev xsltproc python-all-dev python-gps`

```
$ git clone https://github.com/ntpsec/ntpsec.git
$ cd ntpsec/
$ ./waf configure
$ ./waf build
.
  tests that pass 7/7
'build' finished successfully (13.546s)
```

---

**ntpsec**, build-example 2 : Add a **sid** line to /etc/apt/sources.list : Example url →

```
deb-src http://ftp.dk.debian.org/debian/ sid main
```

.... And run `# apt update`

Build ntpsec packages.deb, version "1.1.7+dfsg1-1"

```
$ mkdir ~./tmp
$ cd tmp/
$ mkdir ntpsec-1.17 && cd ntpsec-1.17/
$ apt-get -b source ntpsec=1.1.7+dfsg1-1
```

Package build result :

```
ntpsec_1.1.7+dfsg1-1_amd64.deb
ntpsec-dbgsym_1.1.7+dfsg1-1_amd64.deb
ntpsec-doc_1.1.7+dfsg1-1_all.deb
ntpsec-ntpdate_1.1.7+dfsg1-1_amd64.deb
ntpsec-ntpviz_1.1.7+dfsg1-1_amd64.deb
python3-ntp_1.1.7+dfsg1-1_amd64.deb
python3-ntp-dbgsym_1.1.7+dfsg1-1_amd64.deb
```

Link to the 7 packages for Debian Buster https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1y7KYc9SGq04g0a8AAXCGvmDHXasTJL5C?usp=sharing

---

> 08 Oct : building package ntpsec-1.1.3+dfsg1

Probably the most buggy version you can find. Hence the 43 ! patches http://cdn-fastly.deb.debian.org/debian/pool/main/n/ntpsec/ntpsec_1.1.3+dfsg1-2.debian.tar.xz

```
tar xvf ntpsec_1.1.3+dfsg1.orig.tar.gz
cd ntpsec-1.1.3+dfsg1/
tar xvf ntpsec_1.1.3+dfsg1-2.debian.tar.xz
patch -p1 < debian/patches/[forty three times patch].patch
        #### i.e. 43 times patch command ....
./waf configure
./waf build
'build' finished successfully (7.803s)
```

P.S. : The original `ntpsec-1.1.3.tar.gz` https://ftp.ntpsec.org/pub/releases/ntpsec-1.1.3.tar.gz is perfect. The issue with "1.1.3+dfsg1" seems to be caused by the Debian additions / goodies. Version 1.1.7 has these new additions by default : https://github.com/ntpsec/ntpsec

PPS : 'ntp.ntpc' : ntpsec/build/main/ntpclients/`ntp/ntpc.so`

Comment: Above are just your build processes but I don't see any thing that can solve my problem such as how to fix missing **ntp.ntpc** module. By the way, thanks for your packages.

Comment: Please see my edited answer about `ntpsec-1.1.3+dfsg1`